# Exception hierarchy in plsql

Tags: exception, plsql

Is there anything like an exception hierarchy in plsql? I googled this and nothing relevant comes up. I know that we should give the "WHEN OTHERS THEN" as the final part of an exception section. Regarding other exceptions is there anything like a hierarchy? Or do all the exceptions collectively fall under "WHEN OTHERS", and it is in a way the base of all exceptions much like the Exception class in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hierarchy, each exception has its own code (save for user-defined exceptions where you haven't defined a code) which can be used to individually capture the exception. `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS` simply catches *every* exception, which is why it is so dangerous when used improperly.

If you need to capture multiple exceptions in a hierarchical manner, you can specify the order in which you capture them by specifying multiple handlers, for instance:

```
exception 
 when dup_val_on_index then
    insert ...
    raise;
 when user_definex_exception then
    logerror(sqlcode);
 when others then
    raise;
```

This enables you to capture specific exceptions early and handle then as you wish before capturing the remainder (if this is what you wish to do). There's quite a lot of information in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS007).